# Many to Many вывод данных Java

Tags: java

У меня есть БД с тремя таблицами User, Book и User_Book связующая для many to many. Делаю выборку связанных пользователей и книг.

Выборка книг:

```
 List<Book> listOrders = session.createQuery
   ("from BookManager.Model.Book as c inner join fetch c.usersOrder as j").list();
```

Выборка пользователей:

```
   List<User> listOrders = session.createQuery
   ("from BookManager.Model.User as c inner join fetch c.booksOrders as j").list();
```

Далее передаю в jsp

```
    model.addAttribute("listUsers", this.bookService.getUsersOrder());
    model.addAttribute("listBooks", this.userService.getBooksOrders());
```

В jsp таблица с тремя столбцами user.name, book.name, book.author.

**Вопрос** не могу понять как мне в таблице корректно отобразить эти данные.
 С списка достаю объекты

```
  <c:forEach items="${listUsers}" var="user" >

  <c:forEach items="${listBooks}" var="book" >
```

Может я изначально не правильно работаю с БД? Чую где-то туплю, но пока не пойму где именно.

Book:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "books")
public class Book {
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column(name = "BOOK_TITLE")
private String bookTitle;

@Column(name = "BOOK_AUTOR")
private String bookAutor;

@Column(name = "BOOK_PRICE")
private int price;


@Column(name = "BOOK_IMG")
@Lob
private Blob bookImg;

@Column(name = "BOOK_INFO")
private String bookInfo;

public Blob getBookImg()
{
    return bookImg;
}

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "books_users",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "book_id") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") })
private Set<User> usersOrder = new HashSet<User>();

public void setBookImg(Blob bookImg) {
    this.bookImg = bookImg;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getBookTitle() {
    return bookTitle;
}

public void setBookTitle(String bookTitle) {
    this.bookTitle = bookTitle;
}

public String getBookAutor() {
    return bookAutor;
}

public void setBookAutor(String bookAutor) {
    this.bookAutor = bookAutor;
}

public int getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(int price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public String getBookInfo() {
    return bookInfo;
}

public void setBookInfo(String bookInfo) {
    this.bookInfo = bookInfo;
}


public Set<User> getUsersOrder() {

    Hibernate.initialize(usersOrder);
    return usersOrder;
}

public void setUsersOrder(Set<User> UserOrders) {
    this.usersOrder = UserOrders;
}


public void addUser(User user)
{
    Hibernate.initialize(usersOrder);
    usersOrder.add(user);
}
```

User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

@Id
@Column
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column
private String username;

@Column
private String password;

@Column
private int access;

@Transient
private String passwordConfirm;


@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "books_users",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "book_id") })
private Set<Book> booksOrders = new HashSet<Book>();



public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public int getAccess() {
    return access;
}

public void setAccess(int access) {
    this.access = access;
}

public String getPasswordConfirm() {
    return passwordConfirm;
}

public void setPasswordConfirm(String passwordConfirm) {
    this.passwordConfirm = passwordConfirm;
}

public Set<Book> getBooksOrders() {
    Hibernate.initialize(booksOrders);
    return booksOrders;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам надо в entity Book добавить поле List<User>, а в entity User добавить поле List<Book> и правильно описать мапинг для них как для Many to Many. Тогда при запросе в бд вы получите объект пользователя содержащий в себе книги.

Comment: это у меня есть, соотношение mаny to many работает нормально, и в списках верные данные. Я не пойму как мне их вывести правильно на странице.

Comment: давайте сначала определим, что вы хотите получить на jsp, если текстовое описание сложное, нарисуйте и приложите в вопрос

Comment: Виктор, Не правильно прочел Ваш ответ. Вот про "правильно описать мапинг для них как для Many to Many", можно подробнее?

Comment: Добавьте схему бд и классы book и user, попробую помочь, заодно сам разберусь ))

Comment: "Вопрос не могу понять как мне в таблице корректно отобразить эти данные. С списка достаю объекты" - как вы хотите их отобразить? т.е. как должны выглядеть jsp? Добавьте схему в вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку у вас всего 2 таблицы, и в пределах вашего вопроса предложу так:

Убрать ленивую загрузку книг у пользователя, чтобы лишний раз не бегать, забирайте сразу пользователей с их книгами. При этом в Book оставить ленивую загрузку пользователей.

Тогда в jsp вы идете по пользователям и у каждого их них проходите по книгам.

```
  <c:forEach items="${listUsers}" var="user" >
      <c:foreach items="${user.booksOrders}" var="book">
        //тут в таблицу вкладываете значения
        //userName = <c:out value="${user.name}"/>
        //BookAuthor = <c:out value="${book.bookAutor}"/>
        //BookTitle = <c:out value="${book.bookTitle}"/>
      </c:foreach>
  </c:foreach>
```

Этот кусок корректируете исходя из требований оформления.

также после первого foreach можно написать

```
 <jsp:useBean id="user" class="package.User.class">
```

Если работаете через IDEA Ultimate это добавит интеграцию, т.е. оперировать вы будете не Object, а объектом конкретного класса.

id - название переменной на jsp странице
class - класс которому принадлежит объект.

---

Если не хотите убирать ленивую загрузку, то просто перед отправкой листа на страницу пройдитесь по всем пользователям и загрузите книги.

Comment: Хорошая идея, только у меня она не совсем правильно работает. В списке users пользователи дублируются(т.е. количество повторений пользователя соотносится количеству купленных им книг). Поэтому в таблице данные повторяются.

Comment: @ksg sql на получение пользователей поправьте на  ("from BookManager.Model.User ").list(); т.к. книги у вас будут лежать в пользователе. В вашем случае и правда пользователи начинают дублироваться.

Comment: ,такой запрос  будет доставать с бд всех пользователей без разбора. Как вариант конечно можно, потом проверять пустой список книг у пользователя или нет, и в случае положительного результата работать с ним. Но если из 100 пользователей мне нужны только 10, как то неправильно вроде)

Comment: @ksg тогда просто положите пользователей в сет, дубликпты удаляться. Либо напишите чистый  sql запрос с distinct. Либо с помощью hql where c.booksOrders != null, или c.booksOrders.size > 0

Comment: Вопрос полностю решен, спасибо добрый человек за помощь.